# Can also a teacher say "同学们好！" ？

Tags: usage

If "同学们好！" means "Hello classmates!", can also a teacher say that to its students, despite the fact that the teacher is essentially not a classmate / not part of the student group?

I ask this because my Chinese textbook suggests that a teacher could say this. So I am a bit confused now.

Comment: I get your point of course, and @Tang Ho has cleared it up. Just for comparison, how about a teacher in a school in ,say, the US greeting her class of 5 year olds with "Good morning children" ?

Answer (score 7):

When a teacher or any outsider says 同学们, 同学 is referred to as a "student"

Example:

张同学，李同学 = classmate Zhang, classmate Li (from a classmate's standpoint, but it is too formal, typically classmates just address each other with their full names)

张同学，李同学 = student Zhang, student Li (from a teacher or any outsider's standpoint)

同学们好 = "hello students" or "hello class"

Answer (score 2):

In China School, before teaching, always say:
Teacher: 同学们好！
Students: 老师好！

teacher is not part of the student group

Answer (score 1):

同学 has two meanings:
1 classmate
2 student

So a teacher can definitely say 同学们, which means students. A teacher can also say **同学, which means student **.

Answer (score 0):

"同学" shows a special relationship between you and the student. If you are a student, it means you are classmates, schoolmates,etc. If you are a teacher, it shows you teach them.

However, you can always use it to shorten the distance between you and the person you refer.